# How to minimize smoke/liquid output when roasting chicken?

Tags: chicken, roasting

Last spring I discovered [this recipe](http://www.buzzfeed.com/christinebyrne/roast-chicken-rules#.ip698lP7G) for roast chicken. It's a winner: simple, reliable, and tasty. I have two quibbles:

1. It produces enough smoke to set off the smoke alarm, even with the exhaust fan at high speed.
2. Even if I rest the chicken for fifteen minutes after roasting, it still emits huge amounts of liquid when I carve it.

How can I reduce liquid/particulate emissions from this bird?

Answer (score 1):

As far as smoking: Use a [roasting rack](https://www.google.com/search?q=roasting+rack&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiUrdGn0oLKAhUC-mMKHaH-CVIQsAQIaA&biw=1280&bih=587) in the pan, and put enough water in the pan to not allow the dripping fat to burn. Keep the chicken above the water and check the water level during roasting.

As far as the liquid exuded: Be sure that you are using a chicken that has not been "pre-basted" (injected with a flavor/sodium solution). Slash the skin of the chicken, especially the dark meat, before roasting. That will give extra liquid an avenue for escape. Don't slash the breast meat, as that will likely dry out the chicken before it is done.

Comment: The idea of slashing makes me cry out for those delicious juices. I definitely agree re: the super brined/injected birds. To me 15 minutes is just too short a rest.

Comment: It could go either way, certainly really juicy dark meat isn't a negative for everyone. I have seen it though, particularly in pre-basted birds. Puddles. Not wet enough to be unattractive to me, but I have a thick skin for such things. I don't believe that resting a chicken for more than 15 minutes would ameliorate that, but I welcome you to add insight.

Comment: Roasting rack: already using one. Won't putting water in the bottom create too much steam?

And no, I don't buy pre-basted chickens.

Comment: @crmdgn - In comments from the link you provided, someone suggested putting potatoes in the bottom of the pan to absorb the fat to avoid the smoke.